# Error handling in task scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is there a way to catch an exception using the task:scheduler?

Here's my example:

```
<task:scheduler id="aggregatorReaperScheduler" />

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="aggregatorReaperScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="aggregatorReaperBean" method="run" initial-delay="${loyalty.aggregator.reaper.scheduler.initialtimeout}" fixed-delay="${loyalty.aggregator.reaper.scheduler.timeout}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

thanks in advance!

Regards

Guzman

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean directly instead of `<task:scheduler>` and use its `errorHandler` property to inject an instance of `org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler`. In this case you can use `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`, of course, to publish those errors to some channel.